# how to remove outer ( ) from string contain multiple ( ) in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string which contain multiple inner "( )". I need to remove the "()" surrounding the string.

`myString = "(A-01: FLURO ENGINEERING P LTD.(HIWIN))"`

I want this:

`myString = "A-01: FLURO ENGINEERING P LTD.(HIWIN)"`

I am having difficulties removing the outer ().Please help

Comment: It looks like parenthesis are not in your string, but around it, forming 1-tuple. And 1-tuple for `Swift` is same as just a value contained inside. So, I don't understand what's your problem is.

Comment: Please show your code. As @user28434 pointed out, the parenthesis are most likley not part of the string. We need to see the greater context.

Comment: @user28434 - Please see now

Comment: Anyone know how to do it

Comment: It now looks rather different: the parenthesis are now inside the double quotes. Is this a delibarate change? Did the original question contain an error, which has now been corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you are sure you will always have outer "()"** that are part of the string itself you can achieve that in multiple ways, one way is:

```
var myString = "(A-01: FLURO ENGINEERING P LTD.(HIWIN))"

myString = String(myString.dropFirst())
myString = String(myString.dropLast())

print(myString)
```

Which prints out:

> `A-01: FLURO ENGINEERING P LTD.(HIWIN)`

**If you are not sure, but would like to remove outer "()" in case they are both present**, you can simply, as one solution just check it like this before dropping first and last character:

```
if myString.first == "(", myString.last == ")" {
    myString = String(myString.dropFirst())
    myString = String(myString.dropLast())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression

```
let string = myString.replacingOccurrences(of: #"^\((.*)\)$"#, 
                                           with: "$1", 
                                           options: .regularExpression)
```

Comment: Thats wrong @DarkDust, it actually produce `abc (def) hi`